# Is the category of left modules is isomorphic to the one of right modules?

Tags: category-theory, modules

Given a ring $R$, it is said in "Abstract and concrete categories" by Adamek et al. (p 25) that the category of left modules $R\textbf{-Mod}$ is isomorphic to the one of right modules $\textbf{Mod-}R$. I cannot figure how. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is incorrect. The correct statement is that the category of left modules over $R$ is equivalent to the category of right modules over the opposite ring $R^{op}$.

If $R$ is a division ring, then the categories of left $R$-modules and left $R^{op}$-modules are equivalent if and only if $R \cong R^{op}$ as rings (look at the endomorphism ring of the unique-up-to-isomorphism simple object), and there are examples of division rings not isomorphic to their opposites coming from the theory of Brauer groups.

Comment: Note that in the book, it's written that $R$ is commutative.